# Fill the Left 25% of a Circle with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I want to create a figure similar to this one:

### [image: Picture of Circle].

The left "quarter" of the circle should be filled (as if the circle is intersected by a hyperplane and all points in the circle that are one the left side of the hyperplane are marked). However, I only managed to create such a figure in the case when the left half of the circle is filled. This was my attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill] (0,0)-- (90:2ex) arc (90:270:2ex) -- cycle ;
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help is very appreciated. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could clip a rectangle that has just a quarter of the width of the circle: `\begin{scope} \clip (0,0) circle (2ex); \draw[fill] (-2ex,-2ex) rectangle (-1ex,2ex); \end{scope} \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2ex);`.

Comment: \fill[teal] (210:1) arc(210:330:1) -- cycle;